# Algorithm for checking timeouts

Tags: algorithm, queue, timeout

I have a finite set of tasks that need to be completed by clients. Clients get assigned a task on connection, and keep getting new tasks after they finished the previous task. Each tasks need to be completed by 3 *unique* clients. This makes sure that clients do not give wrong results to the tasks.

However, I don't want clients to take longer than 3000ms. As some tasks are dependent of each other, this could stall the progress.

The problem is that i'm having trouble checking timeouts of tasks - which should be done when no free tasks are available.

At this moment each tasks has a property called `assignedClients` which looks as follows:

```
assignedClients: [
  {
    client: Client,
    start: Date,
    completed: true
  },
    {
    client: Client,
    start: Date,
    completed: true
  },
    {
    client: Client,
    start: Date,
    completed: false
  }
]
```

All tasks (roughly 1000) are stored in a single array. Basically, when a client needs a new task, the pseudo-code is like this:

```
function onTaskRequest:
  for (task in tasks):
    if (assignedClients < 3)
      assignClientToTask(task, client)
      return

   // so no available tasks
   for (task in tasks):
      for (client in assignedClients):
        if (client.completed === false && Time.now() - client.start > 3000):
          removeOldClientFromAssignedClients()
          assignClientToTask(task, client)
```

But this seems very inefficient. Is there an algorithm that is more effective?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is store tasks in a priority queue (which is often implemented as a heap) by when they are available with the oldest first.  When a client needs a new task you just peek at the top of the queue.  If it can be scheduled at all, it can be scheduled on that task.

When the task is inserted it is given now as its priority.  When you fill the task list up, you put it in at a timing that is the expiry of the oldest client to grab it.

If you're using a heap, then all operations should be no worse than `O(log(n))` as compared to your current `O(n)` implementation.

Your data structure looks like JSON, in which case https://github.com/adamhooper/js-priority-queue is the first JavaScript implementation of a priority queue that turned up when I looked in Google.  Your pseudocode looks like Python in which case https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html is in the standard library.  If you can't find an implementation in your language, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure) should be able to help you figure out how to implement it.